# refresh web page for one user after event in another user's browser

Tags: php, events, cakephp

I have this website where I have implemented a pretty simple messaging system between 2 users in PHP (using CakePHP to be more accurate).

It all works fine, one user sends a message and the other user receives it. The only problem is that the second user has to refresh the page to see the message.

Is there any way I can tell the second user's browser to refresh when the first user sends a message? Messages are stored in a MySQL database. When a user goes to the messaging page, I show all the messages from last to first that belong to him, pulling them from the database.

The easy way would be to make some javascript function that periodically refreshes the page, but that's not the best solution, and can be annoying for the user. Ideally, the page should refresh when the user receives a new message...

Another way I've been thinking about is to make an AJAX call to a function, passing somehow the datetime of the last received message when the user entered the page, which then checks for a newer message, and if true, refreshes the page. This wouldn't be bad if I managed to make it work, but still would imply other problems in this page with other stuff that's going on.

Is there any other way to do this?

Comment: I think you should use periodical `ajax` check.

Comment: What are the "other problems" you would get if you checked for new messages periodically via AJAX? You have to have some connection to get data from server to client Other ways to get that would be Websockets or a Comet-like connection.

Answer (score 3):

Have a look into Socket.io and Node.js. They allow you to do real time things such as that and socket.io is backwards compatible to older browsers.